# Need to create a function that takes a value from an array, stores it, then places it in a second array using only .pop and .push

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have to solve this exercise for a course I'm taking on JS:
"Create a function that takes two arrays as parameters, takes out the last value from the first one, then puts it into the second one." The commands I'm expected to use are .push and .pop, I can't use concat or any command other than those two.

The course presents you with an example of what the function should do:

```
let anArray = [1, 2];
let anotherArray = [3, 4];

move(anArray, anotherArray);

anArray //should be [1]
otroArray //should be [3,4,2]
```

This is what I've written so far:

```
function move (parameter,parameter2){
 var anArray = [1,2];
 var anotherArray = [3,4];
 var storage = anArray.pop();
 anotherArray.push(storage);
}
```

I'm really confused as to why I can't get it to work. I'm really new to JS and would really appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance,

Luis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't use your function parameters, but defined new variables.
This would work:

```js
function move(parameter, parameter2) {
  var storage = parameter.pop();
  parameter2.push(storage);
}
let anArray = [1, 2];
let anotherArray = [3, 4];

move(anArray, anotherArray)
console.log(anArray)
console.log(anotherArray)
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I'd been struggling with this for two days already adding extra stuff that wasn't needed. Thank you a whole lot, you've saved me.

Comment: Glad, I could help you!

Comment: @LuisArgüelles Could you please accept the answer? Would be very kind. Have a good one.

Comment: Earlier it said it was too soon to do so, thank you so much once again!

Answer (score 0):

Because in the function `move` you defined `anArray` and `anotherArray` again. The scope of outer arrays is different than the scope of the variables defined inside.
Actually the moving is happening in the arrays defined inside the method. Since you've defined them with the same names hence the confusion.

Please see below for the implementation that you have made which is actually working but not on the parameters being passed

```js
function move(parameter, parameter2) {
  var anArray = [1, 2];
  var anotherArray = [3, 4];
  var storage = anArray.pop();
  anotherArray.push(storage);
  console.log(anArray)
  console.log(anotherArray)
}

move([],[])
```

So in order to make your function work on the input params you are passing then you can actually make the changes like below

```js
function move(parameter, parameter2) {
  const storage = parameter.pop();
  parameter2.push(storage);
}

let anArray = [1, 2];
let anotherArray = [3, 4];

move(anArray, anotherArray)
console.log(anArray)
console.log(anotherArray)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've solved it already but this works too! I learned quite a bit reading through your code and the other person's. I really appreciate it.